# Before and After Slider with Multiple Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a page that has before and after images that use a slider based on mouse movement to show both images.  I need to have multiple sliders on the page and can not seem to get them to work.  Below are a couple of different examples I have found and the challenges I am having.

http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/JDphy - This works well with mobile but I can not seem to add a second version without adding css for every image since the background image is embedded in the css.

```
div#inked-painted { 
  position: relative; font-size: 0; 
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
div#inked-painted img { 
  width: 100%; height: auto; 
}
div#colored { 
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/colored-panel.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

http://codepen.io/ace/pen/BqEer - Here is the other example that does not work as well with mobile.  I can add the second image but the slider works all the images simultaneously and not individually when a second image is added.

Can anyone help with adding the second image.  I am sure both of these are very workable but I am missing something in my css/javascript knowledge that is not allowing multiple images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop though all classes to be able set the eventhandlers individual. Your codepen example could be change to this to work with individual images at once:

```
var blackWhiteElements= document.getElementsByClassName("black_white");

for (i = 0; i < blackWhiteElements.length; i++) {   
  initCode($(blackWhiteElements[i]));
}


function initCode($black_white) {
var img_width = $black_white.find('img').width();

var init_split = Math.round(img_width/2);

$black_white.width(init_split);  

        $black_white.parent('.before_after_slider').mousemove(function(e){
        var offX  = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $black_white.offset().left);
            $black_white.width(offX);
        });
        $black_white.parent('.before_after_slider').mouseleave(function(e){
        $black_white.stop().animate({
        width: init_split
        },1000)
        });
}
```

codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJPmKV

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did make one minor change to keep the slider from going back to the center on mouse out.  I removed the .animate call.  I am also going to keep working to make it responsive

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt is near sufficient.

- Assign the background-image inline in the html to avoid extra classes

`<div id="colored" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/colored-panel.jpg);"></div>`

- change `background-size` on `#colored` to `background-size: auto 100%;` to reduce the "shaky" effect

`background-size: auto 100%;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but when I added a second image they did not seem to work.